# C++ vector subscript out of range when trying to print second element

Tags: c++, vector

I have the error "Expression: vector subscript out of range".
This is what my vector looks like:

```
std::vector<const char *> imagePaths{ "space.jpg", "playerSprite.png"};
```

I am getting the error when I do this line of code:

```
std::cout << imagePaths[1];
```

But there are 2 items in the vector.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you seen in the debugger?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nreIpChlSXXyWTcQ). Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Alex It was an error like this: http://prntscr.com/9az6n9

Comment: @HugoCornel Are you sure it's referring to that `std::cout` line?

Comment: @Jamey D When I remove the cout statement, the program runs fine...

Comment: @HugoCornel, just stop on a breakpoint and check the vector content.

Comment: `std::cout << imagePaths.at(1);` produces the same error? Always prefer the method with bounds checking.

Comment: @DeiDei http://prntscr.com/9az8qm

Comment: @Alex I set a breakpoint just before the cout statement and the vector size was 1, not 2.

Comment: Why are people disliking the question while there is still not an answer?

Comment: What is the value of `imagePaths.size()`?

Comment: @MikeCAT 1. But I put 2 elements in my vector.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @MikeCAT How to see in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Hugo Cornel, please post  your actual code. The code that you posted should work.

Comment: @ZDF I already fixed it. I declared the vector in my header file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize a vector use an array for C++03:

```
const char* arr[] = {"space.jpg", "playerSprite.png"};
std::vector<const char *> imagePaths(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

For C++11 it's even easier:

```
std::vector<const char *> imagePaths = { "space.jpg", "playerSprite.png"};
```

**Edit:**

Are you sure the debug assertion is coming from `std::cout << imagePaths[1];` ?

Comment: @HugoCornel The `std::vector` constructor copies them

Comment: When i initialize the vector with the = symbol, as you said, it still does not work, same error.

Comment: When I remove the cout statement, the program runs fine...